# Can't stop Mysql 5.1 on Mac OSX 10.6

Tags: mysql, macos, shutdown

I'm trying to stop Mysql v5.1 on MacOSX 10.6 so that I can upgrade to Mysql v5.5.

I believe I installed v5.1 from source many months ago. I've attempted all the methods listed here: [How do you stop MySQL on a Mac OS install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100948/how-do-stop-mysql-on-a-mac-os-install).

However when I do a "mysqladmin shutdown" it seems the os just spawns another mysql process:

```
$ sudo mysqladmin shutdown
$ ps -Af | grep mysql
   74 53283     1   0   0:00.01 ??         0:00.01 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
   74 53324 53283   0   0:00.01 ??         0:00.03 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/var/Al.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/var/Al.local.pid
  501 53343 52577   0   0:00.00 ttys003    0:00.00 grep mysql
```

The same thing happens if I try to kill the process. (However if I try to kill the mysqld_safe process I get "No such process")

I've looked in /Library/StartupItems and there's no MySQL directory. I know I didn't use MacPorts to install Mysql.

What am I missing here? How do I slay this beast?

Comment: your mysqld_safe's parent PID is 1, which means it's `init`. So your mysql is being started as part of system start up. I'm not familiar at all with OSX, but is there a /etc/init.d or similar on top of the startupitems folder?

Comment: Justin - even a kill -9 doesn't kill it:

    $ sudo kill -9 53283 53324
    Password:
    $ ps -Af | grep mysql
       74 54610     1   0   0:00.01 ??         0:00.02 /bin/sh /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe
       74 54672 54610   0   0:00.08 ??         0:00.10 /usr/local/mysql/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/var --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/var/Al.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/var/Al.local.pid
      501 54674 52577   0   0:00.00 ttys003    0:00.00 grep mysql

Comment: Marc B - you provided the hint! As it turns out there is a file: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist that was preventing mysql from shutting down. Once I removed it and rebooted mysql went away. This stackoverflow post has more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555589/mysql-5-5-10-mac-10-6-x-auto-start

Comment: Marc B - if you post the answer I'll check it. Thanks for the keen eye!

Answer (score 12):

@Sly -- your fix works nicely. However, if you didn't want to restart I found (in `man launchctl`) that you can also make it stop restarting mysql by issuing the following command:

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

PS: Your com.mysql.mysqld.plist file may be in /Library/LaunchDaemons or /Library/LaunchAgents or in ~/Library/LaunchDaemons or ~/Library/LaunchAgents

Comment: I had a similar issue (though no processes showed up) but this helped. I think it had to do with not unloading during a reinstall.

Comment: In my case the path was slightly different: /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar install without the launcher daemon.  I run mysqld in a terminal.  I find the only way I can shut it down is by sending signal 11 to the mysqld process.

Comment: this works like a charm, just type "kill -11 <process_id>" on the terminal then press return will save your day ;)

Answer (score 1):

MySQL is started using launchctl   take help of launchctrl to unload it

```
  launchctl interfaces with launchd to load, unload daemons/agents and generally control launchd
```

Try unload the should resolve the Issue

```
sudo launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

if mysql has not loaded using the launchctl utilty then unload will not stop the mysql then in this case the regular `sudo mysqladmin shutdown will work`