# Autostart MySQL Server on Mac OS X Yosemite/El Capitan

Tags: mysql, osx-yosemite, osx-elcapitan

I would like to auto start the MySQL server on startup. This was possible in Mavericks but seems to be not working on Yosemite.

**edit**: seems this works with El Capitan as well

[image]

Answer (score 143, accepted):

@dcc was very close. This is how MySQL autostarts again on Yosemite:

The `com.mysql.mysql.plist` in `/Library/LaunchDaemons`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Additionally I've changed the permissions based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555589/mysql-5-5-10-mac-10-6-x-auto-start#5557091)

```
sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
sudo chmod 644 /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Finally I run this command

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

If you have any addition please share below!

Comment: You should mark your Q answered so other people will find your solution.

Comment: I dream about the day when OSX 10.11 will arrive and I won't have to spend 2 hours to fix apache, php and mysql. Maybe it's time to move to Vagrant..

Comment: It really works. BTW, the first two commands can be combined into one: `sudo chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist`

Comment: Very useful to have this to cut down on my two hours getting these working again! Thanks guys.

Comment: Matches the solution posted earlier here: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6604544

Comment: Worked for me - thanks. By the way, the chances are that if you're reading this, you will also have discovered that your copy of Apache doesn't work at startup either. If your Apache comes from Macports, the fix for this is similar: `sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.apache2.plist`. I found that the .plist file was still intact in the directory.

Comment: @revaxarts Well, thanks to you it took me only 2 minutes... :) Thanks

Comment: Y'all saved me 115 minutes!

Comment: In my case the user running MySQL was: _mysql. You can check the current user with the command: dscacheutil -q user | grep mysql

Comment: Thanks first half the reboot solved, now to get Tomcat to start

Comment: After upgrading from Yosemite to El Capitan, this was only part of my problems. This part was indeed solved within two hours: MySQl is started again. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This code causes my System Preferences to crash on El Capitan when I click 'MySQL'.

Comment: works! had this problem for months, finally found the solution.

Answer (score 13):

I followed [@Xavers directions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465743/2947502) and upon trying to execute the command

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

was given the error:

> /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist: Invalid property list

After scratching my head for a minute I found that removing the DOCTYPE DTD declaration at the top made the error go away and upon restart mySQL server is, indeed, running.

So, my XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--user=mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you **installed mysql with homebrew**, you can get instructions on how to autostart it by typing `brew info mysql`.

For example, the output on my machine is:

```
To have launchd start mysql at login:
  ln -sfv /usr/local/opt/mysql/*.plist ~/Library/LaunchAgents
Then to load mysql now:
  launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
```

Answer (score 2):

Create `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist` and save it with the following plist:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?-->

<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>KeepAlive</key>
        <true>
            <key>Label</key>
            <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
            <key>ProgramArguments</key>
            <array>
                <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
                <string>--user=mysql</string>
            </array>
        </true>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

Then load the newly created plist file

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Comment: doesn't work, it still says "stopped" after a restart :(

Comment: `apachectl start`starts the server!? are they related?

Comment: The `sudo launchctl load -w...` throws an error `Invalid property list`

Comment: i'm out of possibilities, sorry

Comment: ok, thank you anyway, I'll post the solution if I'm able to get one

Comment: seems the XML is not formatted correctly - `true` is closed right before `</dict>`. I managed to get this working again, thanks for you input!

Comment: The accepted answer causes my System Preferences to crash, but this one doesn't. Don't know if it fixed the auto-restart though.

Comment: This answer did not work in autostarting MySQL on OS X 10.11.3.

Answer (score 2):

This article help me resolve the issue with invalid error. Corrected plist I used below.

[How to know which line of plist file is incorrect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488872/how-to-know-which-line-of-plist-file-is-incorrect)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-   1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict> 
<key>KeepAlive</key> 
<true/> 
<key>Label</key> 
<string>com.mysql.mysqld</string> 
<key>ProgramArguments</key> 
<array> 
<string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string> 
<string>--user=mysql</string> 
</array> 
</dict> 
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the other provided answers worked to auto-start my MySQL server. I followed the instructions from [the MySQL 5.6 handbook](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/osx-installation-launchd.html) and it finally auto-starts again! Create the file `/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" 
  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>             <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>       <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>     <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>          <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>         <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>       <integer>600</integer>
    <key>Program</key>           <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--user=_mysql</string>
            <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
            <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
            <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
            <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
            <string>--port=3306</string>
        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>  <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

And run the following commands after creating the file:

```
cd /Library/LaunchDaemons
sudo launchctl load -F com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist
```

Answer (score 0):

When I used the plist suggested in earlier answers, I changed the user to _mysql for my system, but the "Stop MySQL Server" button in the MySQL preference pane no longer worked. The `KeepAlive` key will cause the process to launch again immediately after the Stop button is pressed. I used the key `RunAtLoad` to get it to just start on reboot, but allow the button in the pane to continue working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
    <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--user=_mysql</string>
    </array>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

Then, as in the other answers, ran:

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.mysql.mysql.plist
```

Now, MySQL launches on restart, but the MySQL pane in System Preferences still works.
I'm running El Capitan, 10.11.2