# How to get MySQL server working after OSX Yosemite upgrade?

Tags: mysql, joomla, osx-yosemite

After I upgraded my Mac from Mavericks OSX to Yosemite, my local Apache and MySQL server setup did not work anymore. Thanks to [Apache localhost/~username/ not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24583859/apache-localhost-username-not-working#comment40163424_24622039) I just got the Apache server working but my Joomla application now indicates it can't access the MySQL database; neither can the Phpmyadmin tool.

How to fix this? I've seen instructions for installing MySQL for Yosemite (https://www.computersnyou.com/3376/setup-apache-php-mysql-macosx-10-10-yosemite/) but I'm not sure whether that's the best way forward as my Joomla application still needs to access the existing MySQL db information? E.g., I don't want to lose my existing saved database info of various web applications....

Comment: This is not about programming. Actually its off-topic.

Answer (score 3):

If you had a working native version of mysql working on Mavericks, the mysql preference pane should be still visible in the preferences, just click on the preference pane and start mysql.

Only problem is that mysql does not auto-start on boot, this can be solved by following these steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26465743/580173

[image: preference pane Yosemite, Mysql]

Answer (score 2):

Just Start MySQL Server! It worked for me.

[image]

Comment: mine still showed "stopped" after clicking the Start button and giving my password, but somehow this seems to have done the trick