# Yosemite - MAMP - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)

Tags: macos, mamp, mysql.sock

I have problem when I try to connect to MySQL MAMP :

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I'm doing research but I have not found a solution to my problem, I try to link mysql.sock like this :

```
sudo ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
```

But, the file /tmp/mysql.sock doesn't exist.

Do you have any ideas ? The problem is blocking me for 2 days, I searched for this time but nothing good for me.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error #2002 Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11105796/error-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-applications-ma)

Comment: you have to start the sever first. so click on the blue elephant status icon in the menubar and select *Start servers* then the MAMP will create a socket in the tmp file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I solved it following these steps:

1. I stopped and restarted MySQL via System Preferences -> MySQL (see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/26523977/204807)
2. I entered `sudo mysql_upgrade` in a terminal window, and pressed <kbd>enter</kbd>

After the update process I was able to connect with my MySQL.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem after upgrading MySQL on MAMP from 5.5 to 5.6 version. 
After long research I founded this decision https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/32402/drush-and-mysql-database-with-mamp-connection-problem

In my case there was no socket file at that location  `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock`.

The easy solution is to create a symlink:

```
cd /tmp
ln -s /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock ./mysql.sock
```

The effect of which is to route all calls for /tmp/mysql.sock to the appropriate MAMP specific path.

Comment: This helped me !! Thanks a ton Galina. I tried all suggestions in this chain but finally, yours helped me. It may be useful to explain a little more why this problem occurs in the first place and why was this link you suggested not created by default?

Answer (score 15):

simply remove two files ib_logfile0 and ib_logfile1 from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56

Comment: Works like a charm in High Sierra! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

In some cases /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock.lock may create the problem. remove .lock and it will work (OSX)

Comment: Your Rock! save my day

Comment: In my case, completely removing the mysql.sock.lock file worked.

Comment: none of the above method works, only your is working. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Rename `.sock` file of mysql and restart your MySQL server.

`/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock` to `/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql_old.sock`

Comment: renaming the mysql.sock did not help me.

Comment: share your error here.. exactly what you are getting.

Comment: @AaronMarton :-)

Answer (score 2):

Also check to make sure MySql is running. You can get this error if you try to use MySql from the command line when MAMP/MySql is not running.

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps anyone, I got past this roadblock by:

1. Stopping all other versions of MySQL (I forgot that I had Oracle MySQL starting on system launch and I was attempting to connect via that installation.) and removing them anyway to let MAMP handle it.
   Use `sudo launchctl unload -F /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`
2. Ensure MAMP is running.
3. Running /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql.

Comment: Tried to shut down oracle MySQL but this still did not help starting the MAMP MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

1) `mysql.server stop`

2) `/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh &&`

now on MAMP go to

`Tools => Upgrade MySQL databases`

Comment: You can't upgrade the database if it won't start.