# Starting MySql after migration Yosemite

Tags: mysql, macos, osx-yosemite

I've run into a problem here, and I'm not sure what to do.  I migrated a Yosemite Mac to a new Mac Pro.  Apache turns on, but MySql does not with this error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (XAMPPErrorDomain error 1.)
I didn't know if I need to reinstall MySql or upgrade it, or what this error means.   I created the plist file as in [the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26461173/autostart-mysql-server-on-mac-os-x-yosemite) and ran permissions, but that did not change the outcome. Going to websites in localhost, WordPress shows an error establishing db connection. 
I went to [Github](http://www.macminivault.com/mysql-yosemite/) to install MySql and it went fine, but it does not work with Xampp and Desktop Server.  I chose to NOT start MySql when I rebooted, but apparently the Github version started anyway (and I cannot find a  way to turn it off!) Now when I try to start MySql from Xampp, it says another version is already running.
Any help appreciated.

When I ask for version number in terminal I get this response:

mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!

HOWEVER, when I went to /var/ and temp I found an alias for mysql.sock, BUT it was not connected to an original file... Now that file does not exist anywhere on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Open `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/xampp` and add this line somewhere at the top:

```
unset DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: Thank you Muhammad. I will save this answer

Answer (score 0):

I found that what was required was a complete uninstall of MySql following this procedure: http://bytearrays.com/completely-uninstall-mysql-mac-osx/

And then a reinstall.  ServerPress.com was very helpful in diagnosing the problems.