# Mysqld cannot stop with Mac

Tags: mysql

I ran `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop` with Terminal and it showed

```
Shutting down MySQL
. SUCCESS!
```

But very weirdly the next command `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` did not work, showing the following message.

```
151103 19:45:27 mysqld_safe Logging to '/usr/local/mysql/data/Marshalls-MacBook-Air.local.err'.
151103 19:45:27 mysqld_safe A mysqld process already exists
```

I went to System Preferences -> MySQL to find out if it is still running, and it turned out to be yes.

Now I started the Activity Monitor, to forcefully quit mysqld. I clicked the quit button, and it still turns out to be active.

Any solutions?

Comment: *consider* undoing the auto-start, with something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26465743), or it in reverse (I honestly didn't read it for setting off auto-start). Then do an o/s restart. Voila, no mysql daemon running. and proceed as you were.

Answer (score 6):

This indicates that MySQL server is running on your Mac. If you would like to kill/stop the process for any reason, do the following:

1. Go to **System Preferences...** -> **MySQL**
2. click on **Stop MySQL server**.

you are done. :)